# Взаимодейстие с клавиатурой на C/C++

Tags: c++, c, автоматизация, клавиатура

1-2 дня назад я задал вопрос, но не совсем корректный, поэтому сейчас я постараюсь поставить его более правильно. 
Допустим, есть игра, в которой нужно нажимать на одну из клавиш клавиатуры. Я, как человек ленивый, хочу все это действие автоматизировать, поэтому в моих мечтах написать приложение на Си/Си++, которое открывается вместе с игрой и вместо меня посылает сигналы от нажатых клавиш клавиатуры в игру. Вот я и хочу знать, возможно ли такое приложение создать на Си/Си++? Если возможно, то подскажите, пожалуйста, что читать и куда смотреть, буду благодарен.

Comment: Ничего не делать, но при этом играть?.. Это не получится игрой, а получится что то типа  видиопросмотра

Comment: Вы хотите написать кликер?

Comment: @goldstar_labs что-то вроде того

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хмммм, на винде через [SendInput()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx), к примеру.

А вот если вам нужно, чтобы приложение запускалось с игрой - сделайте наоборот:

1. Пишете приложение, которое при запуске порождает процесс с игрой, т.е. не игра запускает вашу программу, а наоборот.
2. Далее меняете объект ярлыка вашей игры с самого лаунчера игры на ваше приложение.
3. Радуетесь.